# Is $Y \cup_f X$ a CW complex?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

Let $A$ be the subcomplex of a CW complex $X$, let $Y$ be a CW complex, let $f: A \to Y$ be a cellular map, and let $Y \cup_f X$ be the pushout of $f$ and the inclusion $A \to X$. My question is, is $Y \cup_f X$ a CW complex with $Y$ as a subcomplex and $X/A$ as a quotient complex?

Comment: It is true that $Y \cup_f X$ is a CW complex with $Y$ as a subcomplex. This is proven in Theorem 2.3.1 in "Cellular structures in topology" by Fritsch and Piccini (page 62).